# Populate multi select with selected values in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multi-select

I have stored multiselect values in database as string

[image]

Now while trying to edit the values in need to fetch this highlighted string as array and send it to edit view , so that i can populate multi select with this selected values.

My code in view for multi select

```
 <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">News For
                                <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                   {!! Form::select('news_todisplay[]',['users'=>'Users','staff'=>'Staff','cinemahall'=>'Cinemahall'],$todisplayarray,array('class'=>'form-control','multiple'=>'multiple')) !!}


                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Where $todisplayarray is the array fetched from database i.e they are users,staff, cinemahall

My controller code

```
 public function edit($id)
{

    $newsdetails=General_news::findOrFail($id);
    $todisplayarray=explode(',',$newsdetails->news_todisplay);
    return view('admin.editnews',compact('newsdetails','todisplayarray'));
}
```

Page view-source shows this

```
 <select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name="news_todisplay[]"><option value="users">Users</option><option value="staff">Staff</option><option value="cinemahall" selected="selected">Cinemahall</option></select>
```

This only shows last value as selected, where as it should display 3 of the values as selected.

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Find the below answer

```
<?php  
//get the old values from form
$old = old('category');

//get data from database table field
$cate= explode(',',$data->category_ids); 

//stay the values after form submission
if($old){  $cate=$old; } 
?>
<select id="categories"  name="category[]" multiple>
    @foreach ($categories as $val)
       <option value="{{ $val->id }}" <?php echo in_array($val->id,$cate)?"selected" :"" ;?> >{{  ucfirst($val->category_name) }}</option>  
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I've used loop the categories data with id's and match the data stored in the table